# More intuitive way for solving this problem than using the multinomial theorem?

Tags: combinatorics

I'm the TA in a discrete math course and there was a problem in this weeks problem set which I had troubles solving. It goes like this:

Find the coefficients of $v^2w^4xz$ in the expansion of $(3v + 2w + x + y + z)^8$.

The multinomial theorem (which I had to look up and have never seen before) solves this very easily, but is there a more intuitive and beginner-friendly way to solve it? These students are 1st year CS majors. I haven't actually taken this particular course myself, but I took another disc. math course which covered slightly more material, but I've never even seen a problem about expansions of multinomials, and it's slightly embarassing that I couldn't solve it without having the answer fall right out of a theorem.

Comment: You mean the [Multinomial Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem).

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Oops, yes I do. I'll edit.

Comment: Also, to which power is the polynomial $3v + 2w + x + y + z$ being raised?

Comment: @N.F.Taussig 8th power. I guess this typos is what happens when I ask a question here at 1 a.m.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To obtain a $v^2w^4xz$ term from the expansion of $(3v + 2w + x + y + z)^8$, we must select $3v$ from two of the eight factors, $2w$ from four of the remaining six factors, $x$ from one of the two remaining factors, and $z$ from the only factor we have not yet used.  We can make these choices in 
$$\binom{8}{2}\binom{6}{4}\binom{2}{1}\binom{1}{1} = \frac{8!}{6!2!} \cdot \frac{6!}{2!4!} \cdot \frac{2!}{1!1!} \cdot \frac{1!}{1!0!} = \frac{8!}{2!4!1!1!} = \binom{8}{2,4,1,1}$$ 
ways.  Hence, the coefficient of $(3v)^2(2w)^4xz$ is
$$\frac{8!}{2!4!1!1!}$$
Since 
$$(3v)^2(2w)^4xz = (9v^2)(16w^4)xz = 144v^2w^4xz$$
the coefficient of the $v^2wxz$ term is 
$$\frac{8!}{2!4!1!1} \cdot 144 = 840 \cdot 144 = 120960$$

Comment: Great! This is exactly what I was hoping for.

Comment: Glad I could help.  Please get some sleep.